# Need a prometheus library for flink 1.3.3

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, flink-streaming

We are planning to use Prometheus for metrics monitoring and currently most of our applications run in FLINK 1.3.3 .Is there any Prometheus metrics jar for this ?

I checked maven ..Dont see anything beyond 1.4.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-metrics-prometheus/1.4.0

Comment: I am afraid that Flink 1.3 does not support prometheus. The page regarding this version has nothing saying about prometheus. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html . but the version 1.4 already has https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/metrics.html

Answer (score 3):

The Prometheus metrics reporter was new in Flink 1.4. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6221.